# how to change $arr['news'] into echo

Tags: php, arrays, json, pdo

please help, i am learning json, but i find it difficult to insert code echo. If you know the answer please help me

**My Code**

```
if ($result) {
    $arr['news'] = '';
    $idterakhir = '';
    $query = $pdo->query($sql);
    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        // change this into echo
        $arr['news'] .= '<div class="card" news_id="'.$row->news_id.'">'.$row->news_id.'<br>'.$row->news.'</div>';
        // change this into echo
        $idterakhir = $row->news_id;
    }
    $arr['idterakhir'] = $idterakhir;
    $arr['end'] = false;
} else {
    $arr['end'] = true;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

**into :**

```
echo "
     <div class='card' news_id='$id'> $id  <br> $title  </div>
    ";
```

Comment: dont json_encode if you clearly dont need/want json output. You are already composing the HTML output that you seem to need. Just echo it `echo $arr['news'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    $id2 = $row['news_id'];
    $id = <div class="card" news_id="'.$id2.'">
    $news = $row['news'];
    $title = $id.$id2.<br>'.$news.'</div>        
    $arr['news'] .= title;
    echo $arr['news'];
    $idterakhir = $row->news_id;
}
```

This should print `$arr['news']` for each circle of the while.

Comment: @dickynugroho hidayatulloh I edited it, check it now, if you are changinge the `$arr['news']` with `$arr['news'] .= '<div class="card" etc... ` you can echo it after that.

Comment: or this, how to insert in my code :
 $id2   = $row['news_id'];
   $title2  = $row['news'];

Comment: What you want to do with that I dont get it

Comment: I want to make it easier to write $ on <div class = "card" news_id = "'. $ row-> news_id.'"> '. $ row-> news_id.' <br> $ title2 '. $ row-> news.' </ div>

Comment: sorry i pay less attention :D

Comment: how to remove the dot on my code : '<div class="card" news_id="'.$id2.'">'.$id2.'<br>'.$title2.'</div>';

start = '.$title2.'
into = $title2

Comment: The dot represent string adition, you can replace them with variables, I tried to do it in a eddit but I think it won't work cause I tried to separete it too much.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to echo out the contents of `$arr['news']`, just do:

```
echo $arr['news'];
```

Comment: can not be like this :
include("data.php");
         echo "
         <div class='card' news_id='$id'> $id  <br> $title  </div>
        ";

Comment: Its really difficult to understand what you want to do